# Unable to instantiate fragment androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Error

**Unable to instantiate fragment androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public.**

ActivityLayout

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/app_nav" />
```

Activity

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
class MovieListFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_list, container, false)
    }
}
```

Dependency Used:

```
implementation('android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha07') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
implementation('android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha07') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```

Comment: What's your android studio plugin version?

Comment: android studio version 3.2, gradle version 3.2.0

Comment: That's wired. Try invalidate cash and restart, clean and build.

Comment: that's not the solution

Comment: what is the issue that appear to you ?

Comment: did you convert the project to suppport androidx ?

Comment: @M.G yes already converted to androidx.

Comment: Post your activity and Fragment code.

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån updated the activity and fragment code

Answer (score 14):

If its happening only on the proguarded version, you might have forgotten to add the proguard rule. Add the below rule in your proguard file

```
-keepnames class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.1.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version" // For Kotlin use navigation-fragment-ktx
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version" // For Kotlin use navigation-ui-ktx
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happen when you are not set `navigationGraph` correctly. May be it is a bug or not. There are below reason this error occurred.
 Accidentally you add `HomeActivity` in your `navigationGraph` and also added `MovieListFragment` and connected `MovieListFragment` to `HomeActivity`. And then delete HomeActivity from graph. So the `MovieListFragment` id not changed may be its krrp the map. I found this issue in my project. Event i reopen the project but nothing luck. So i delete `MovieListFragment` from graph (only from graph). Then again add the `MovieListFragment` then it working again.

> In my project `HomeActivity` was `MainActivity` and
>   `MovieListFragment` was `DashboardFragment`.